# Bundling multiple JARS into one and choosing specific one from client app

Tags: java, android, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm working on a library jar (more like a wrapper on other libraries) which has dependency on more than one other library jars. I know that I can create a one jar/fat jar using eclipse and ship it. For example- I have three library jars: Alib.jar, Blib.jar and Clib.jar. Say Alib.jar has dependency for Blib.jar. I can make a fat jar say fatlib.jar which packages three of them.

```
(Alib.jar --> Blib.jar) + Clib.jar == packages into ==> fatlib.jar (common APIs)

fatlib.jar == used by ==> client app
```

The fatlib.jar provides a common API interface for client app. This common APIs make use of Alib.jar, Blib.jar and Clib.jar, and picks the right classes as requested. Say, when client app not using APIs depending on Clib.jar, client app should have flexibility for dropping the Clib.jar while building itself (most probably an APK). I want to give client app option to pick the dependency library jars that it really needs while building.

Wondering if this is possible at all? I'm dreaming about some tool like Fat Jar eclipse plug-in which shows you all the jar that you can pick or drop while building a jar. May be probably not. 
So Here is the question: Is it possible to choose the internal jars from a parent jar at compile time?

Comment: There's really no need. Just utilize ProGuard and it will strip away the unused code.

Comment: wondering if it is possible to use ProGuard for building jars as well?

Comment: Yeah, it is: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/